# How to transpose and skip cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, libreoffice

thanks for being so helpful. I have columns where every 6th column had an alphabet letter: a b c d e f, so that column 1 has letter a, column 7 has letter b. I want to transpose that into rows of a b c d e f without any skipping, so that now row 1 has letter a, row 2 has letter b, and so on. How would I do that?

Comment: Show an example of your current sheet and what is the wanted result.

Comment: How many rows of data are there in each column? Should the data of each column be transposed or merged into the same for each alphabet letter?

Answer (score 0):

Enter to **B2** `=OFFSET($A$1;0;(ROW()-1)*6)` and fill down

Comment: Thanks Johnsun, but when i pasted that into B2, it said that formula did not work.

Comment: Yes, it can be. I don't know what country you are from and what locale settings you have. Maybe your Calc expects `VERSCHIEBUNG()` or `DESREF()` instead of `OFFSET()` and `ZEILE()` or `FILA()` instead of `ROW()`.  Please try setting the **Use English function names** option in [**Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Formula**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01060900.html) and enter the formula again.